# Exploding an array and removing prefix

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, explode

I an trying to create an array using explode for a string.

Here is my string:

```
$string = "a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7";
```

And here's my complete code:

```
$string = "a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7";
$d = explode(',', $string);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($d);
```

and after that i got the result like this..

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "a:1"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "b:2"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "c:3"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "d:4"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "e:5"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "f:6"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "g:7"
}
```

How can I create an array like this instead?:

```
array(7) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["b"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["c"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["d"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["e"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["f"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["g"]=>
  string(1) "7"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php 
foreach($d as $k => $v)
{
    $d2 = explode(':',$v);
    $array[$d2[0]] = $d2[1];
}
?>
```

Comment: ```$array``` must be initialized first ```$array = array();``` before ```foreach```

Comment: @Gtx PHP handles this without error though I agree that it *should* be initialised

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
$arr = array();
$d = explode(',', $string);
for($d as $item){
   list($key,$value) = explode(':', $item);
   $arr[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Colosus\modul\barang\explode.php on line 19

Comment: @Wawan Guessing I'd need to look at your actual code, guessing there's a missing `;` somewhere, or a stray brace.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution using loops:

```
$string = "a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7";
$pairs = explode(',', $string);
$a = array();
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    list($k,$v) = explode(':', $pair);
    $a[$k] = $v;
}
var_export($a);
```

You can also do this (in PHP >= 5.3) in a more functional manner:

```
$string = "a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7";
$pairs = explode(',', $string);
$items = array_map(
    function($e){
        return explode(':', $e);
    },
    $pairs
);
$a = array_reduce(
    $items,
    function(&$r, $e) {
        $r[$e[0]] = $e[1];
        return $r;
    },
    array()
);

var_export($a);
```